# How to parse POST response body in Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

```js
    
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.crypto);
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is running in port 3000");
});
```

```js
    
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});
app.post("/", function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.crypto);
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is running in port 3000");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bitcoin ticker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Bitcoin Ticker</h1>

  <form action="/" method="post">
    
    <select name="crypto">
      <option value="BTC">Bitcoin</option>
      <option value="ETC">Ethereum</option>
      <option value="LTC">Litecoins</option>
    </select>

    <select name="fiat">
      <option value="USD">US Doller</option>
      <option value="GBP">GB Pounds</option>
      <option value="EUR">EU Euroes</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" name="button">Check</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

have an issue in javascript code when iam requesting for post request the browser says  Cannot read property 'crypto' of undefined 
when iam running the code there is no error but when iam selecting cannot read 
property "crypto"
and i think the errror might be in here 
console.log(req.body.crypto);

Comment: Please share the relevant codebase but from the error i am guessing that you are trying to import nodejs 'crypto' module on browser

Answer (score 2):

Your `req.body` is undefined,

you have to make this line

```
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

to

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `req.body` is undefined.

Guess the problem is with the `body-parser`.

Try changing this line

```
app.get(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

To

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Instead of applying `body-parser` with `app.get`, do it with `app.use`

Answer (score 0):

`Subburaj` and `Ron537` are both correct because `body-parser` is a `middleware` and in `express` you use the method `use` to include a `middleware` to your express program. in your case to include the body-parser `module/middleware` in your app, do `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))` if you want to be posting both sub-document and  `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))` if you dont want to be posting sub document